# Can't see logs generated in actor system during unit test runs on play framework 2.4.X?

Tags: playframework, akka

I'm doing unit test to my playframework application, but I can't see logs generated by the actors while running the test...

any tip for solving this issue ?

To see the logback.xml visit:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6uge1urz8ewktc/logback.xml?dl=0

Comment: Maybe post your logback.xml and application.conf.  What log level are the statements at? Do they work normally outside the unit tests? What's your logger line look like? Are you looking for actor-lifecycle logs?

Comment: If II execute the project with run all the logs are visible... but during unit test the logs of the actors are not visible ...

Comment: The logback is in this URL: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6uge1urz8ewktc/logback.xml?dl=0

Comment: Have you enabled logback debug mode to triage further? `-Dlogback.debug=true`

Comment: My dear friends... the problem was between the keyboard and the desk.. sorry ! Totally my fault !